# Explicit basis of eigenvectors of improper rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $R = \begin{pmatrix} \cos (\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & -\cos(\theta) \\ \end{pmatrix}$. Then we need to find a basis or eigenvectors $q_{1}$, $q_{2}$ giving an explicit orthogonal matrix $Q_{0}$ such that $\det(Q_{0}) = 1$ and $$Q_{0}^{-1}RQ_{0} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\\ \end{pmatrix}.$$ Here’s my progress. I have $$R(\theta) - \lambda I = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta) - \lambda & \sin(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta) & -\cos(\theta) - \lambda \\ \end{pmatrix}.$$ Then $$\det(R(\theta) - \lambda I)  = (\cos(\theta) - \lambda)(-\cos(\theta) - \lambda) - \sin^{2}(\theta).$$ If we set $\det(R(\theta) - \lambda I) = 0$, we have $\lambda = \pm 1$. Then I first consider the case when $\lambda = 1$. Then I  want $$\begin{pmatrix} \cos (\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & -\cos(\theta) \\ \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}.$$ Then essentially, I have $x \cos (\theta) + y \sin(\theta) = x$ and $x \sin(\theta) - y\cos(\theta) = y$. Then I think that $\langle \cos(\theta/2), \sin(\theta/2) \rangle$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$, but I’m confused about how to go from here to solve my problem. Could anyone help me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the matrix equality you are seeking should be $Q^{-1}_0RQ_0=....$.

Comment: @AnuragA Yeah, you are right. I've edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solve the system
\begin{align}
x(\cos \theta -1)+y\sin \theta &=0 & \implies -x\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+y\cos\frac{\theta}{2}&=0\\
x\sin \theta-y(1+\cos \theta)&=0 & \implies x\sin\frac{\theta}{2}-y\cos\frac{\theta}{2}&=0.
\end{align}
From here, we get the eigenvector for $\lambda=1$ as $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\\\sin \frac{\theta}{2}\end{bmatrix}$.

Now do the same for $\lambda=-1$.
\begin{align}
x(\cos \theta +1)+y\sin \theta &=0 & \implies x\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+y\sin\frac{\theta}{2}&=0\\
x\sin \theta+y(1-\cos \theta)&=0 & \implies x\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+y\sin\frac{\theta}{2}&=0.
\end{align}
From here, we get the eigenvector for $\lambda=-1$ as $\begin{bmatrix}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\\-\cos \frac{\theta}{2}\end{bmatrix}$.

Your $Q$ matrix can now be written as
$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}&\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\\-\cos\frac{\theta}{2} & \sin\frac{\theta}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$